# SQLite multiple query - best design approach to improve performance

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

i'm new to programming with DB and not an expert in android programming so bear with me!

I have a DB with 2 tables (A and B) where I get a list of ID from the table A (1 to 100 rows) and get rows from table B for each id I got from table A giving me a total of 400 to 800 rows from table B.

This approach is not ideal for my app as it take 4 to 10+ seconds to process where I would ideally want less than 1s.

I'm trying to understand what would be best in a case like this.

- Would having less row but more content in each help?
- the DB is aprox 15mb Would loading it all in the background be better (I guess not as it would mean 5 min+ of loading)?
- what is most expensive / have the worst performance: queries, cursor iteration, loading data from a field?
- I have no specific index with my DB, would generating some help? If so how can I do that?

I currently have the bellow code collecting my data:

```
        Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (cursorTableA.moveToNext()) {

        long id = cursorTableA.getLong(0);
        int paragraphNunber = cursorTableA.getInt(1);
        boolean isPoetry = (cursorTableA.getInt(2) != 0);

        Paragraph mParagraph = new Paragraph(id, paragraphNunber,isPoetry);

        // GET WORDS
        String selectionWords = DbContract.WordsEntry.CONNECTED_PARAGRAPH_ID+ " = ?";
        String[] selectionWordsArgs = new String[]{ Long.toString(paragraphNunber) };
        String sortOrder = DbContract.WordsEntry.WORD_NUMBER+ " ASC";

        Cursor cursorTableB = db.query(
                DbContract.WordsEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                DbContract.WordsEntry.DEFAULT_QUERY_COLUMNS_TO_RETURN,
                selectionWords, selectionWordsArgs, null, null, sortOrder
        );

        while (cursorTableB.moveToNext()) {
            String word = cursorTableB.getString(0);
            String thesaurusRef = cursorTableB.getString(1);
            String note = cursorTableB.getString(2);

            mParagraph.addWord(new Word(word,thesaurusRef,note));
        }
        cursorTableB.close();
        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
        timeElapsed = finish- start;
        System.out.println("DB Query => timeElapsed(s): "+(timeElapsed/1000)+" timeElapsed(ms): "+timeElapsed);
    }
```

I should add that my DB is only used in read only, I copy it on first execution to the data/data/.../databases folder I never write in it.

Comment: Why not use a join to get all your results with a single query?

Comment: I'm guessing you also don't have the appropriate indexes set up.

Comment: @Shawn correct, my DB have no indexing I would love to use some if it would help but have literally no clue how to do that or where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a JOIN of your two tables and get just one cursor to iterate instead of get two and nest them. Try something like this:

```
final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM table_a a INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.other_id";

Cursor cursorTable = db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, null);

while (cursorTable.moveToNext()) {
    String id = cursorTable.getString(0);
    String paragraphNunber = cursorTable.getString(1);
    boolean isPoetry = (cursorTable.getInt(2) != 0);
    String word = cursorTable.getString(3);
    String thesaurusRef = cursorTable.getString(4);
    String note = cursorTable.getString(5);
}
cursorTableB.close();
long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
timeElapsed = finish- start;
System.out.println("DB Query => timeElapsed(s): "+(timeElapsed/1000)+" 
timeElapsed(ms): "+timeElapsed);
```

Of course you will have to handle the logic of the creation of the object Paragraph as you will now have a cursor with as many rows as in tableB and "paragraph_id".

Comment: Wow I was not expecting it to give so much difference, I went from 5-10+ sec processing to less than 500ms. This is really good! thank you for this suggestion I wasn't thinking about it but it made the trick!